# Subtracting TimeDate Columns

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas, datetime

I have a CSV file that contains start-time and end-time for sessions.

I would like to understand how I can do End-time - Start-time to get the duration of a session.

So far I have this and it works

```
start_time = "2016-11-09 18:06:17"
end_time ="2016-11-09 18:21:07"
start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

diff = (end_dt - start_dt) 
duration = diff.seconds/60 
print (duration)
```

but I want to do it for the whole column at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import from a csv and then manipulate the date, [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is the way to go.  Since the only info you gave about your data was start and end time, I will show that.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=['start_time', 'end_time'],
                 infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)

df['time_delta'] = df.end_time.values - df.start_time.values
print(df.time_delta)
```

**Test Data:**

```
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(u'\n'.join([x.strip() for x in """
    start_time,end_time,a_number
    2013-09-19 03:00:00,2013-09-19 04:00:00,221.0797
    2013-09-19 04:00:00,2013-09-19 05:00:00,220.5083
    2013-09-24 03:00:00,2013-09-24 05:00:00,221.7733
    2013-09-24 04:00:00,2013-09-24 06:00:00,221.2493
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]))
```

**Results:**

```
           start_time            end_time  a_number
0 2013-09-19 03:00:00 2013-09-19 04:00:00  221.0797
1 2013-09-19 04:00:00 2013-09-19 05:00:00  220.5083
2 2013-09-24 03:00:00 2013-09-24 05:00:00  221.7733
3 2013-09-24 04:00:00 2013-09-24 06:00:00  221.2493

0   01:00:00
1   01:00:00
2   02:00:00
3   02:00:00
Name: time_delta, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Hey Stephen, I get this error when I run it...  TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'infer_datetime_format'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: 0.12.0 This is the version

Comment: That is a really old version...  Can you upgrade?  If not, remove the infer parameter, also what format are your dates in?

Comment: Strange though I updated it an hour ago, I will try again. It's in Year, Month, Day , Hour, Min, Sec +00. eg. 2016-11-09 18:21:07+00

Comment: So it does subtract end_time from start_time, I'm just trying to figure out how to find the min, max and avg duration in this new list

Comment: This question is too many questions in one.  If my example gets you going on pandas and the date subtraction, I suggest you form a new question specific to pandas with a sample data set and expected output.  Then put the pandas keyword on it. That keyword will almost certainly get you answers if you have a well formed question with good data and expected output.  Remember the people who spend time answering these questions live on reputation.  So more *good* questions to answer, the more reputation to earn.  So don't try to cram everything you need to know into one question.

Comment: @Silas, So good job on the new question.  You forgot the data at first, but you got it there.  You got a good answer.  Try not to keep asking too many more questions in the comments.  Upvote, accept, go study the answer. Then in  few hours or so, ask a new question incorporating the things you learned.  Add the biggest problem you are currently facing.  Do not forget the data, the expected output or what code you are already using to get what progress you already have...

Comment: Thank you Stephen

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to run diff against strings, instead of datetime values.

How about something like this?

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime(2016, 11, 12, 18, 06, 17)
end_time = datetime(2016, 11, 09, 18, 21, 07)
diff = end_time - start_time
print(diff.seconds / 60)
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Hey Rick, no the code I posted works fine, but I have a longer list of start_time and end_time with dates and time. How can I do it in one go and create a new column Duration

Comment: Hi Silas, Thanks for letting me know... I missed that it was working. Sorry. But it seems that Stephen Rauch provided you with a interesting answer. Sorry for misunderstanding.